# Javascript: Calling nested function from dynamicaly created instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, oop, object

I am trying to create multiple instance of same function, but wants to preserve their own properties. so that when the button created in 1st instance, the onclick event of that should be pointed to the function from same 1st instance. but (this) keyword not working in this case. i know something else need to be done.

JS:

```
function updateAlias(mac, realName, displayName) {

  var prevHtml = jQuery("#" + mac).html();

  var formHtml = "<input type='text' id='alias-" + mac + "' value='" + jQuery.trim(displayName) + "' />";
  formHtml += "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' onclick='" + this.apply() + ";'>Apply</button>";

  jQuery("#" + mac).html(formHtml);

  var apply = function() {
    alert(mac);
  };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="id1">
  <div onclick="new updateAlias('id1','android-8112ad950b0bca36','device 1')">Device 1</div>
</div>

<div id="id2">
  <div onclick="new updateAlias('id2','android-8112ad950b0bca36','device 2')">Device 2</div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amitshahc/zg74v4k3/9/

Comment: Appear to have duplicate `id`s in `document` at `<div id="id1">` ?

Comment: even if i changed it to id1-id2, the question remains same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed a little in your code.

1. Updated id of second div to id2
2. Added click handler using jquery.

HTML:

```
<div id="id2">
    <div onclick="updateAlias('id1','android-8112ad950b0bca36','device 1')">Device 1</div>
</div>
<div id="id2">
    <div onclick="updateAlias('id2','android-8112ad950b0bca36','device 2')">Device 2</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 function updateAlias(mac, realName, displayName) 
{
  var prevHtml = jQuery("#" + mac).html();

  var formHtml = "<input type='text' id='alias-" + mac + "' value='" + jQuery.trim(displayName) + "' />";
  formHtml += "<button id='"+mac+"-apply' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' >Apply</button>";

  jQuery("#" + mac).html(formHtml);
  jQuery("#"+mac+"-apply").click(function() {
    alert(mac);
  });

}
```

Comment: NP @AmitShah. If it is working fine. Mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead use jQuery event handlers and `data-*` attributes to store the data like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.editor').on('click', '.display', function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' value='" + $.trim($(this).text()) + "' />" + "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Apply</button>");
  });

  $('.editor').on('click', 'button.btn', function() {
    alert($(this).closest('.editor').data('name'));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="editor" data-name="android-8112ad950b0bca36" data-display="device 1">
  <div class="display">Device 1</div>
</div>
<div id="id2" class="editor" data-name="android-8112ad950b0bca37" data-display="device 2">
  <div class="display">Device 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @arun-p-johny, using jQuery it will work. but just curious if there is any core javascript method can work too?